# "No such file or directory found" for Java temp file object on remote server

Tags: java, database, file, remote-access, bufferedwriter

I am working on an app that uploads a file to a database on a remote server. It receives a string, and I need to create a temp file in order to upload it to the database. It works just fine on localhost, but as soon as I tried to pass it to the server, I got the message "No such file or directory: /var/folders..." (to the temp file location).

Here is the code for loading the file. The admin connection is to a Stardog remote server on port 5820. It is open and I can access it via the web console.

```
public static Connection loadFileToDB (AdminConnection admin, String inputFile, 
        String graphTitle, String fileFormat) throws Exception {
    String prefix = graphTitle;
    String suffix = "." + fileFormat;

    // Write input (string) to file object
    File temp = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
    bw.write(inputFile);
    bw.close();

    // Load file and then delete it
    Connection conn = admin.memory(graphTitle).create(temp).connect();
    temp.delete();

    return conn;
}
```

It makes sense that it can't find it, since it is looking for it at /var... which is not on the server, but how can I make it so this file object IS on the server? Thanks!

Comment: you need permissions to create the directory on the server.

Comment: How would I go about setting those permissions? Thanks!

Comment: do you have access to the server? Are you allowed to create the directory manually? If not you can look into using the FTP library. It has a make directory api you can use. That is, if your server encapsulates ftp

Comment: I have access to the server via terminal. It's a AWS instance with an Ubuntu image, so I can connect to it with my keypair & the public IP address. I could create the directory manually, but I'm just not sure how to link it in the application.